# Full e-Commerce solution with multiuser and multistore Magento setup

Tags: multistore, multisite

I would like to know that, is a structure possible with Magento Community Edition like below;

1. We'll setup a magento store **(main store - main site)** with all of our products that can be sold on any sub-store.
2. We'll setup some sub-stores (**with multi-store functionality)** on different domains
3. We'll assign one or more users they responsible to admin these stores **(admins can only manage their sub-store/site)**
4. We'll assign some of our products to these sub-stores (based on sub-store admins' decisions)
5. Admins can edit products(prices-campaigns-images etc)/pages/posts on their sub-stores (own site)

I mean, we would like to construct an e-commerce system to allow our customers let them create their own internet site with their domain and sell our products within these site, we'll provide our host and product database and help them to construct site and store.
Is it possible with magento? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alper,

1. **We'll setup a magento store (main store - main site) with all of our products that can be sold on any sub-store**

This possible at magento.It is default available at magento

2. **sub-stores (with multi-store functionality) on different domains**

**Answer**: Possible,default available at magento.Need to Assign Multiple domain at same ip and same folder.

3. **Assign one or more users they responsible to admin these stores**

Answer: Possible, Create multiple admin user basic of admin section access.

4.**some of our products to these sub-stores**

**Answer** :Possible,default available.Need to follow magento product format